# Why does Google Meet Report Audit Logs API not synchronous?

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to use `Google Meet Audit Activity Events API` to get the report of the meeting room activities. But as i can see that the result is not match with the real, for example: I start a new meeting room, and stay in the room for about 5 minutes, but after joined room for 2 minutes and also after all people leave the room, i run the `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/meet?eventName=call_ended`, there is no any records was returned, i have to wait for a couple minutes or more than 5 minutes later, the report with that URL will return full data. Is this a bug of Google or because of my PHP script having a problem? Is there anyway to get the report realtime when the meeting is ocurring?

Here is my sample script:

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly');
$client->setSubject('<email_of_user>');
$service            = new Google\Service\Reports($this->client);
$userKey            = 'all';
$applicationName    = 'meet';
$optParams          = Array('eventName' => $eventName);

$reports = $service->activities->listActivities($userKey, $applicationName, $optParams);
print_r($reports->getItem());
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, it takes a certain amount of time for the new data to propagate across the system before it's available via the API.

The data isn't available 'real-time', as in it will not reflect the state of the meeting at the exact moment of the request - the API returns a saved report of the meeting activity rather than directly fetching the information live from the room. The same can be said for all Workspace APIs.

Comment: So maybe the realtime report will be a future feature, right? We can only get the full report after the call ended a few minute, i guess.... :(

Comment: @HungDang I'm not aware of an open feature request for it... but you could always file one yourself at [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)